# python list comprehension by step of 2

Tags: python, list

`xlabels = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]`

Is there a way to step through a list comprehension by 2?

```
for i in range(0,len(xlabels)):
    xlabels[i]=""
```

becomes `["" for i in xlabels]`

It turns the list into blanks. output: `["","","",""]`

what about?:

```
for i in range(0,len(xlabels),2):
    xlabels[i]=""
```

I want to turn every other item in the list into a blank. output: `["", "second", "", "fourth"]`

Comment: This is non sense: a list comprehension defines a new list. You cannot define a new list while skipping every second element...

Comment: Hmm...`for i in range(0,len(xlabels),2): xlabels[i]=""`'s output is `['', 'second', '', 'fourth']`.

Comment: @KevinGuan oops, just changed it

Comment: How about `xlabels[::2] = [""]*((len(xlabels)+1)//2)`. This modifies the original list, like in your `for` loop version.

Comment: @Blckknght Or less efficient but simpler: `xlabels[::2] = [""] * len(xlabels[::2])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track by using `range()` with step. List comprehensions tend to create a new list instead of modifying the existing one. However, you can still do the following instead:

```
>>> xlabels = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [xlabels[i] if i % 2 != 0 else '' for i in range(len(xlabels))]
['', 2, '', 4]
```

Comment: exactly. Also it creates a new list instead of modifying the existing one `xlabels` so you'll have to reassign `xlabels` the result.

Answer (score 10):

Personally, I'd use a list slice and list comprehension together:

```
>>> full_list = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']
>>> [element for element in full_list[::2]]
['first', 'third', 'fifth']
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need it to be more general, you could also do this:

```
>>> xlabels = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]
>>> [i%2 * label for i, label in enumerate(xlabels)]
['', 'second', '', 'fourth']
```